# Tilemap is shaking on camera move in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I am creating simple 100x100 tilemap using `Tiled` and `Phaser`, nothing more, but when I move the camero around, the "map scrolling animation" is not smooth, and there are noise/breaks/shakes of the map. I have no idea what is going on, specially this is only game showing the map. I found somewhere that it can be Chrome issue bug regarding animation frame, but it is the same on Firefox.

Can you advise?

https://youtu.be/AOGimEWpdjo

Code example: https://github.com/Lazarencjusz/phaser-tilemap-shakes

I am using `Tiled` to create `json` of the map, then loading it into my app.

Key code is:

Camera creation:

```
  const cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    const controlConfig = {
      camera: this.cameras.main,
      left: cursors.left,
      right: cursors.right,
      up: cursors.up,
      down: cursors.down,
      acceleration: 0.3,
      drag: 0.0017,
      maxSpeed: 0.75,
    };

    this.#cameraControls = new Phaser.Cameras.Controls.SmoothedKeyControl(
      controlConfig,
    );
```

Map is created like:

```
this.#map = this.scene.make.tilemap({ key: AssetTilemapKey.testMap1 })
this.#tileset1 = this.#map.addTilesetImage(
      TiledTileset.grassRoad,
      AsseTilesetImageKey.grassRoad,
    );
this.#map.createLayer(
        TiledLayers.ground,
        this.#tileset1,
      )
```

Comment: How are you moving the camera, can you share the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @winner_joiner this is based on Phaser examples (btw the same issue there)
`
    const cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    const controlConfig = {
      camera: this.cameras.main,
      left: cursors.left,
      right: cursors.right,
      up: cursors.up,
      down: cursors.down,
      acceleration: 0.3,
      drag: 0.0017,
      maxSpeed: 0.75,
    };

    this.#cameraControls = new Phaser.Cameras.Controls.SmoothedKeyControl(
      controlConfig,
    );`

Answer (score 0):

For me the app works smooth, but when I change the configuration to `Phaser.CANVAS`, than it doesn't move anymore sooth. I assume a solution could be to change the configuration (`config.ts`) to `Phaser.WEBGL` instead of `Phaser.AUTO`.

*But actually, **AUTO** should select **WebGL** by default, **if** your PC supports it. So maybe your PC doesn't support **WEBGL**, so this solution might not work for you *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.GameConfig__anchor))*.*

> **btw:** In the *browser-console* you can see with *type* is used
> [image: screenshot Browser Console]

**Update:**

I just use windows, but I found a post in the official [phaser development forum](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/performance-issues-with-safari/1958/2?u=akumagamo) it mentions, that performance issues on Mac Products could be a problem, with the retina display, since it has to high resolution to render fast.

After reading it, I tested making the *game-size* smaller and bigger.
When I made the *game-size* really big, the movement was really choppy. And making the *game-size* smaller made it run smooth even in the `CANVAS` mode.

So after my tests and the information from the article I would ***suggest***, try making the *game-size* in the `config` smaller (for example 700 x 400), if it runs smooth you could try using this smaller size and just scaling up the canvas with css, when needed.
***(if it runs smoother, when it is smaller you found the main reason)***

> **Just a side note:** If you are not going the use **physics** you could remove the `physics` part from the `config`, this also improves preformance.

Comment: I have tried different types (including WwbGL) and I have the same result unfortunately

Comment: oh i see, what Operating System does your computer run on? And what does the browser console show webgl or canvas?

Comment: Uning AUTO type on Mac I get WebGL, I can check it on Windows, what type it gives and do I have shaking but I need it also working smoothly on Mac anyway. Wonder could it be because of M1 chip...

Comment: I found an article in the official phaser forum, and updated my answer with my findings. I hope it helps.

Comment: That almost work, when I made canvas smaller it works pretty smooth, however, when I scale it up, I get breaks in constant timesets, and the graphisc is pixeled out, loss quality. Cannot use that woraround.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Than **I think** you won't be able to use this smoothing function in phaser, since if you shrink the canvas and it work, this is a clear sign of a performance issue. _(**btw.:** If you are not using physics, removeing it from the config, improve als performance)_

Comment: Yes, I was disabling physics also, but with no effect to the performance.

Comment: You could try posting your question in the [official phaser Forum](https://phaser.discourse.group/), maybe someone else knows a solution, but I sadly doubt it.